# How to save tables permanently in voltdb community edition?

Tags: voltdb

I am using volt db community edition and I am creating the tables in volt db database. Once I restart the server all tables stored in database are deleted. How to save the tables permanently in volt db database using command line?

Answer (score 1):

VoltDB Community Edition does not include any durability features.  Those are found in the Enterprise and Pro editions, available at voltdb.com.

Disclaimer: I work for VoltDB.

Answer (score 0):

Just shutdown the server with the command:

```
voltadmin shutdown --save
```

This will create a snapshot that the system use to restore the database on restart. I am also using the community edition, I have tried it and seems to work. Hope it's still useful :)

References are here: [Official Documentation](https://docs.voltdb.com/tutorial/Part4.php)

Disclaimer: I don't work for VoltDB and I don't want to sel my product.